# How to Send sms periodically after a fixed time automatically

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager, smsmanager

I need to send an SMS to a number periodically in background after a fixed time. How can tat be done.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code to repeatedly send sms with a initial delay and delay between each message.

```
static private Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable task = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        sendSMS("123456", "Test Message");
        if (!stopped) {
            handler.postDelayed(this, interval);
        }
    }
};

public void start() {
    handler.postDelayed(task, initialDelay);
}

private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
{
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
}
```